# PostgreSQL query failure

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.3

I have a unique problem with PostgreSQL. After inserting data into a database I try and retrieve everything greater than a specific string. However, it does not return any data. So, I tried this on another machine and it worked. So my problem is that my data is returned on one machine but not another. I tested:

Windows 7 pro desktop running PostgreSQL 9.2 (WORKED)
Windows 8.1 pro laptop running PostgreSQL 9.3 (WORKED)
Fedora 20 running laptop PostgreSQL 9.3 (WORKED)
Fedora 20 running desktop PostgreSQL 9.3 (FAILED)

The following is my test case which is spread across all systems:

```
create table test(key0 character(38) not null, constraint pkey primary key (key0)) with (oids=false);
insert into test (key0) values ('00 00        00        00 0000');
```

The following query is what returns a different result on the machines:

```
select * from test where key0 >= '00 00        00        00 00        00' order by key0;
```

I have absolutely no idea why these this query does not work on the one machine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure, you can try with EXPLAIN in order to show you the execution plan.

Comment: This is what EXPLAIN returned: QUERY PLAN
Sort  (cost=20.49..20.85 rows=143 width=156) (actual time=0.064..0.064 rows=0 loops=1)
  Sort Key: key0
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
  ->  Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..15.38 rows=143 width=156) (actual time=0.035..0.035 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: (key0 >= '00 00        00        00 00        00'::bpchar)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1
Total runtime: 0.094 ms
(7 rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most likely has to do with collation. See this:

```
select * from test where key0 >= '00 00        00        00 00        00' order by key0;
 key0 
------
(0 rows)

select * from test where key0 >= '00 00        00        00 00        00' COLLATE "C" order by key0;
                  key0                  
----------------------------------------
 00 00        00        00 0000        
(1 row)
```

I guess you didn't provide LC_COLLATE parameter for the CREATE DATABASE statement and it copied the system default which happened to be different across your systems.

Comment: How would I fix my table so that I do not need to COLLATE statement?

Comment: You'll have to dump the data with pg_dump, DROP DATABASE and CREATE DATABASE, explicitly providing the desired collation. Edit: well, you could just recreate the column with the collation you want, but that seems less future proof.